# Trying to change the colour of SVG Image Icon upon selection Material UI

Tags: reactjs, tabs, frontend, material-ui

I've created a vertical tab where when clicked the text changes color. I'm trying to change the icon color as well with a separate color. Can anyone help, please

I've tried naming it on the tab style sheet and individually but no result. The code below will show my attempt where I tried creating a class, but an error of Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined appears. If the solution to color the icon and separately can be done with classes then I guess we just have to resolve this error. If not please ignore the error and if there are any other solutions please suggest. thank you

imported files:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Home from './Screens/Home'
import home from './home.svg';
```

Class content:

```
export default class ProfileTabs extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { activeIndex: 0 };

  handleChange = (_, activeIndex) => this.setState({ activeIndex });
  render() {
    const  { classes } = this.props;
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;
    return (
        <nav className= "side-drawer">
      <div style={{letterSpacing: 0.7, left: 70, position: "absolute", marginTop: 40 ,}}>
        <VerticalTabs className={classes.icon} variant="fullWidth" value={activeIndex} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <MyTab  icon ={<img className= "home" src={home}  alt="home" style={{height: 45, left:20, top:20, position: "absolute"}}/*Pay FlatIcon or replace by design *//>}
          label={<p style={{ textTransform:"capitalize", position:"absolute", left:120, top:27.5,}}>
          Home
          </p>} 
</VerticalTabs>



        {activeIndex === 0 && <TabContainer><Home/></TabContainer>}
</div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Styles and other:

```
const VerticalTabs = withStyles(theme => ({
  flexContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  indicator: {
    display: "none"

  },
  root:{
    position:"absolute",
    left:-70,
    top:-40,

  }

}))(Tabs);

const MyTab = withStyles(theme => ({
  selected: {
    color: "White",
    borderRight: "none",

  },
  root: {
  minWidth: 221,
  margin:0,
 paddingBottom:99

  },


}))(Tab);



const styles = theme => ({
  icon: {
    color:"red"
  }
});


function TabContainer(props) {
  return (
    <Typography component="div" style={{ padding: 9 * 3 }}>
      {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ProfileTabs />, rootElement);

ProfileTabs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Current Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined

  28 | return (
  29 |     <nav className= "side-drawer">
  30 |   <div style={{letterSpacing: 0.7, left: 70, position: "absolute", marginTop: 40 ,}}>
> 31 |     <VerticalTabs className={classes.icon} variant="fullWidth" value={activeIndex} onChange={this.handleChange}>
     | ^  32 |       <MyTab  icon ={<img className= "home" src={home}  alt="home" style={{height: 45, left:20, top:20, position: "absolute"}}/*Pay FlatIcon or replace by design *//>}
  33 |       label={<p style={{ textTransform:"capitalize", position:"absolute", left:120, top:27.5,}}>
  34 |       Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. I've refactored your code to separate all the styles, and then used the MUI classes objects to pass your specific style overrides down to their elements. The styles and classes may still need some tweaking - this is a best-bet given the supplied code:

```
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon"; // <== only if you want to use the MUI 'home'

const styles = {
  iconOnlyStyle: {
    color: 'blue'
  },
  myDivStyles: {
    letterSpacing: 0.7,
    left: 70,
    position: "absolute",
    marginTop: 40
  },
  myIconStyles: {
    color:"red",  // <== this will change both label and icon
    height: 45,
    left:20,
    top:20, 
    position: "absolute"
  },
  myLabelStyles: {
    textTransform: "capitalize",
    position: "absolute",
    left: 120,
    top: 27.5
  },
  sideDrawer: {
    // ...styles
  },
  tabRoot: {
    minWidth: 221,
    margin:0,
    paddingBottom:99
  },
  tabSelected: {
    color: "White",
    borderRight: "none"
  },
  tabsRoot: {
    position:"absolute",
    left:-70,
    top:-40
  },
  tabsFlexContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  tabsIndicator: {
    display: "none"
  }
}

class ProfileTabs extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { activeIndex: 0 };

  handleChange = (_, activeIndex) => this.setState({ activeIndex });

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <nav className={classes.sideDrawer}>
        <div className={classes.myDivStyles}>
          <Tabs 
            variant="fullWidth"
            value={activeIndex}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            classes={{
              root: classes.tabsRoot,
              flexContainer: classes.tabsFlexContainer,
              indicator: classes.tabsIndicator
            }}
          >
            <Tab
              label="Home"
              icon={home}
              icon={<Icon classes={{ root: classes.iconOnlyStyle }}>home</Icon>}
              classes={{
                root: classes.tabRoot,
                labelIcon: classes.myIconStyles,
                label: classes.myLabelStyles,
                selected: classes.tabSelected
              }}
            />
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }

}

export default withStyles(styles)(ProfileTabs)
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense or if you need any explanations. The classes prop in the MUI library took me a while to get the gist of when I first used it, but hopefully this helps clear-up how it can work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have actually tried that and have also tried integrating into myTab styles but no results

Comment: Do you still get the same error message when it's moved?

Comment: Well there are no errors the color simply does not apply

Comment: thanks a lot for putting some time into this I really appreciate it, though will this work with a third-party SVG image? Because it seems that this only works with icons from material UI unless I am mistaken

Comment: I've only reference the MUi svg as I know it works. If you're using your own SVG, I can't see why it wouldn't. If using your own, you could still apply styles:

    <Tab
          label="Home"
          icon={home}
          icon={<img className={classes.mySVGstyles} src={home} />}
          ...
    />